# What strings are accepted by the described DFA?

Tags: finite-automata

Could someone clarify what strings are accepted by the described DFA?

> Draw a DFA for the set of all strings with two consecutive 0’s followed by two consecutive 1’s over Ʃ= {0,1}

Comment: Welcome to CS Stack Exchange! I encourage you to read the guide to asking questions. (See the question mark on the upper right.) I've rewritten the title and question for you.

Answer (score 0):

This describes all strings consisting only of 0s and 1s that contain the substring "0011".

For example, these are some accepted strings:

- **0011**
- 0**0011**0
- 11**0011**

These strings are not accepted:

- 010101
- 0
- 001001011